具合 vs. 塩梅 for "condition/state"
塩梅, which can be used in terms of balance/degree of seasoning in cooking can also be used in the context of how a situation is going (like 調子), such as (from my dictionary):

►こういうあんばいで事が運べば　if things go at this ┏rate [pace].
►うまいあんばいにいく　go
well; go all right
・いいあんばいに　fortunately; luckily
・いいあんばいに彼がこの町に転勤になった.　
Fortunately he's been transferred to (work
in) this town.
►この間の試験はどんなあんばいだった.　
How did you make out in the last
exam?
・今日は暑くもなく寒くもなく, いいあんばいですね.　
Today is neither hot nor cold, but
just right.

This seems incredibly similar to 具合, as you can say things like うまい具合に ("in a good way" -> luckily).
I am pretty sure you can use 具合 when talking about taste as well, but it seems あんばい is more commonly used there.
These words seem to occupy very similar situations and have a similar array of usage so I wonder where they differ.

I feel there are several differences:

案配/塩梅 is less common than 具合 and 調子. It's perfectly fine in novels and formal documents, but it's not a word everyone uses in real conversation.
案配/塩梅 tends to refer to subtle nuances, small adjustments, day-to-day randomness, etc. (体の)案配が悪い is uncommon, but I feel it's closer to 調子が悪い than to 具合が悪い (see also What is the difference between 調子【ちょうし】 (choushi) and 具合【ぐあい】 (guai)?).
案配/塩梅 also means "(delicate) discretion", "(seasoned) judgement", さじ加減, 采配, etc. In this sense, 案配 is also used as a suru-verb meaning something like "to judge (and allocate)". For example, you can say "予算は社長の塩梅で決めてください" and "みなさんの役割は先生が案配して決めます".


I found this word from a radio show hosted by seiyuu of an anime, where they describe a character who is fickle and does not reveal their true intentions by saying “いい塩梅” and “塩梅が絶妙”, is this an example of the subtlety you refer to with this word, because I feel 具合 might not fit as well in that case (as they are pointing out the intricacies of the character)

@whatyouexpect 絶妙な塩梅のキャラクター is somewhat a vague phrase, but if someone says it, I imagine a character who isn't particularly prominent, but is carefully designed to play an appropriate role in the story.
